# How to use the output of shell script in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to execute the following shell command

```
timeStamp=$(date +%s)
echo "###### TIMESTAMP IS #$timeStamp #######"
```

I wanted to pass this variable timeStamp to my second job that I am trying to trigger using "Trigger parameterized build on other projects"

```
timeStamp=${timeStamp}
```

I am not getting the value of timestamp in the variable `timeStamp`. 
I have restrictions that EnvInjectPlugin cannot be used. Is there any other option available to pass the shell script output to another parameter.

Thanks,
Ramya.

Comment: You need to create the variable in Jenkins first, assign it in the script and then pass it on. Variables may not be "promoted" from scripts to Jenkins.

Comment: Hi If i Create a varailbe then it takes the default value for that vaiable and this value is not getting assigned

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the EnvInjectPlugin plugin. But since you have restrictions that EnvInjectPlugin cannot be used, you can choose to use property file and here is how.

Step 1:
[image]

Step 2:

> Add Post-build action ==> Trigger parameterized build on other projects ==> Add Parameters ==> Parameters from preperties file

[image]

After that, you can use TIMESTAMP parameter in the downstreamJob.